# How to put a WPF usercontrol inside a WInforms usercontrol?

Tags: wpf, winforms

How to add a **wpf usercontrol** within a **winforms usercontrol**? Tried hosting the Wpf usercontrol using the element host as below.The added child control doesn't show at design and runtime.

```
public partial class WinformsUC: UserControl
{
    public WinformsUC()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        try
        {
           var eH = new ElementHost {Dock = DockStyle.Fill, Child = new WpfUserControl()};
           Controls.Add(eH);
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Log.Debug(Constructor : " + exception.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @user1874589 Are you sure you added Windows usercontrol to the main windows form and added some content within the WPFUsercontrol? It works good for me with your code.

Comment: Yes thats a windows usercontrol not a wpf usercontrol and WPF usercontrol has wpf controls as contents.

Answer (score 0):

you can do that using the [system.windows.forms.integration.elementhost](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.elementhost(v=vs.110).aspx)

Example :

```
private ElementHost ctrlHost;
private UIElement wpfUserControl;

// in the from the load event handler
ctrlHost = new ElementHost();
ctrlHost.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
panel1.Controls.Add(ctrlHost);
wpfUserControl= new WpfUserControl();

//we need to manually call initializecomponent if it is not called
//in the constructor of your control
wpfUserControl.InitializeComponent();
ctrlHost.Child = wpfInputControl;
```